# Pandas Boxplot with Groupby - plot vector arrays in column per category

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

```
LTP,surface_distances
1.0,[3.        2.4494898 3.1622777  0.        0.        0.     9  ]
1.0,"[ 9.530573   9.530573   9.161782   8.731052   9.770159   9.615404
  9.480876   9.399235   9.371863   9.371863   9.371863   9.371863
  8.422484   8.330477   8.206197   9.068727   8.925962   8.839198
  8.54362    8.206197   7.919437   7.6890116  7.5201006  7.3780055
  7.130104   6.4887457  5.864883   5.2647395  9.591869   9.457006
]"
1.0,[0.        0.        0.     3.6649203 3.870587  4.065864 ]
1.0,"[ 7.95181    8.283971   7.7533436  7.1679688  7.4169073  7.854291
  8.127435   8.127435   7.619655   7.0959272  6.6085405  7.3821893
  7.8215146  8.032048   8.032048   8.063969   7.619655   7.1679688
  6.6498694  6.988916   7.3821893  7.8215146  8.         8.
  8.032048   8.127435   7.7533436  7.3798757  6.6498694  6.988916
  7.3821893  7.8215146  8.         8.         8.032048   8.127435
 ]"
```

Read the data in with `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')`
Also added link to the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfplqd04zs9Bigp9Vq8y6HqwDALe00NY/view?usp=sharing

I would like to group the `df[distances]` column by `df[LTP]`which has only 0 and 1 values representing 2 categories.

I have tried:

```
df.boxplot(column=['distances'], by='LTP', ax=ax, return_type='axes')
```

AND to separate into a separate DataFrame with 2 columns.

```
dst_ltp = []
dst_no_ltp = []

for idx, row in df_final.iterrows():
    if row['LTP'] == 1:
        dst_no_ltp.append(row['distances'])
        dst_ltp.append(np.nan)
    if row['LTP'] == 0:
        dst_ltp.append(row['distances'])
        dst_no_ltp.append(np.nan)

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['No LTP at 6m', 'LTP at 6m'], index=range(0, len(dst_ltp)))
new_df['No LTP at 6m'] = dst_no_ltp
new_df['LTP at 6m'] = dst_ltp
df1 = new_df.transpose() # transpose the matrix
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
df1.boxplot(column=['No LTP at 6m', 'LTP at 6m'])
```

AND

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.boxplot(data=pd.melt(df1))
```

**But I still can't get what I want which would be something like this:**

[image]

Comment: result of: `print(type(df.surface_distances.loc[0])` is `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney google link to data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vfplqd04zs9Bigp9Vq8y6HqwDALe00NY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney that's the way I got the data as provided in the google drive link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if this is exactly what you're after.

If you're looking to explode the lists so that each has the corresponding `LTP` label then this should work.

```
import itertools

def flatten(a):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))    

# flatten the list of lists
res = df.groupby('LTP')['distances'].apply(flatten).reset_index()

# explode lists
res = (res['distances'].apply(pd.Series)
              .stack()
              .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
              .to_frame('distances')).reset_index()
res.rename({'index':'LTP'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

# plot the new data
res.boxplot(column=['distances'], by='LTP', return_type='axes')
```

Output

[image: boxplot output]

Answer (score 1):

### This data has issues:

#### Fix the data:

- Using `converters={'surface_distance': eval}` or `ast.literal_eval` will not work because all the rows of data are not properly enclosed with `[]` at both ends.
- This is a full solution, working with the data as it's provided in the Excel file.
- After the format of `surface_distance` is fixed, use [.`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), to separate the lists

  - This function works on a `pandas.Series`, therefore set the index to `LTP`, so each `surface_distance` value is properly assigned to its corresponding `LTP` value.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fix_my_data(x):
    x = x.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').strip().split(',')
    return [float(v.strip()) for v in x if v not in ['', ' ']]

# import the data
df = pd.read_excel('surface.xlsx')

# rename the column
df.rename(columns={'SurfaceDistances_Tumor2Ablation': 'surface_distance'}, inplace=True)

# create a valid list of numeric values
df.surface_distance = df.surface_distance.apply(fix_my_data)

# set index to LTP
df.set_index('LTP', inplace=True)

# pandas version 0.25 use explode to expand all lists
# update pandas if you're not on 0.25
df_sd = df.surface_distance.explode().rename_axis('LTP').reset_index(name='sd')

sns.boxplot(x='LTP', y='sd', data=df_sd)
plt.show()
```

[image]